# How to view get image back from MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql, image

I have uploaded an Image in my database. The datatype is BLOB. Now I want to view this image in my browser. I have written the following code but its not  generating the image. Kindly check it.

Thanks

```
<?php

    include 'connect.php';
    //$id= $_GET['product_id'];

    $query_images = "SELECT image FROM product_images WHERE product_id=121";

    if (!$query_images_result = mysql_query($query_images))
    {
        echo mysql_error();
    }
    else
    {

         $fetch_images = mysql_fetch_array($query_images_result);

         $print_images = $fetch_images['image'];

         header('Content-type:image/jpeg');

         echo $print_images;
    }

?>
```

File 2

```
<body>

<img src='single_product_image_show.php' alt="image" />

</body>
```

Comment: Any particular reason for using a `BLOB` to store the image, rather than just the path to the image in the database?

Comment: what happens when you visit `single_product_image_show.php` directly

Comment: see this once http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/50895-display-image-from-mysql-database/page__view__findpost__p__350380

Comment: @DevZer0 it shows a blank image box.

Comment: @NickR I am making this project in my pc and after completing i will need to run it on others computers that why i am storing images in my database. So it will be easier for me to Import/export data.

Comment: @nickle I have checked this tutorial. Its also saying the same thing that i done here, but still its not giving me the output.

Comment: First: `mysql_query` is outdated for years now. Second: saving images in a database is very bad style! Usually you only put the path/url/id of your file in the database.

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this? You might wanna use [base64 encoding](http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter) to build in the image

**FYI: NOT TESTED.**

```
$sql = "SELECT `image` FROM `product_images` WHERE `product_id`=121 LIMIT 1";

$query_images_result = mysql_query($sql);

    if (!$query_images_result)
    {
        echo mysql_error();
    }
    else
    {

       list($print_images) = mysql_fetch_array($query_images_result);

       $base64source = "data:image/jpeg;base64," . base64_encode($print_images);
       echo '<img src="'.$base64source.'" alt="" />';
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Its working now, but it is only showing part of image not the whole image.[Kindly check it](http://postimg.org/image/5kq9lvztf)

Comment: is the whole image uploaded properly?

Comment: Yes it was uploaded successfully.

Comment: try adding `echo header('Content-type:image/jpeg');` above $base64source

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possible reasons why this could happen. First try your script directly without "header('Content-type:image/jpeg');" so you can see what it actually returns. Like http://[youhostname]/single_product_image_show.php I assume you will see some errors.

Some best practices to serve images from php:

- If you can remove the end php tag (?>). You don't actually need it and you can avoid issues when you have whitespace character after the close tag which will be written to the response and so results as a corrupt image.
- You should specify the Content-Length header as well. It's not mandatory but the browser
  will know how big the file it has to download.
- Specify some cache control headers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) so browsers can cache your image so it won't result a full page load and mysql query every time the image appears on the site.
- You can store ETag and/or Last-modified in the database which you can retrieve and put in the headers.

Comment: I tried the script without header, it generates Binary data and when i add header it shows empty image space.