# Unable to store File details in Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, syntax-error

I am trying to store uploaded file details in my database. I have written the following code, but I am unable to understand why its not reading the Query Block. Its not generating any MySQL error message or any other Syntax error. Kindly check it.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="file_upload_test2.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="file" name="file2" id="file"><br>
<input type="file" name="file3" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>



</body>
</html>


<?php

include 'connect.php';

$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));


if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
//&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 200000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 200000) . " kB<br>";




        $image_name=        $_FILES["file"]["name"];  

        $path=              move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                                    "upload/" . rand().$_FILES["file"]["name"]);            

            echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];     

            if (mysql_query ("Insert into category_images (image_name,image_location) VALUES ('$image_name', '$path')"))
            {
                echo "successfull"; 
                } 
                else {
                    mysql_error();
                    } 
      }
    }

else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }


?>
```

Comment: first of all, do not use mysql_* as it is depreciated.  secondly, is echo "Stored in:" echoing anything?

Comment: ok next time i will take care of it and  Yes 'echo stored in' showing the path ; Stored in: upload/paint.png

Comment: Try `echo mysql_error();` to show mysql error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `category_images` (`image_name`,`image_location`) VALUES ('".$image_name."', '".$path."')";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if ($result)
    {
          // Successful query execution
          echo "successfull"; 
    } 
    else {
          // Some error occured while executing query.
          // Show some useful information using echo/print.
          // Then stop execution after taking other necessary steps

          die(mysql_error());
    }
```

also, your database is vulnerable to SQL Injection attack since you are not sanitizing your input. You should use at least [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) method to ensure that this doesn't occur.

If the above doesn't work, try checking if your connection parameters are ok and if MySQL is running.

Comment: I just paste these line in my code and comment the old ones. Its not generating any error message but also not showing any result.

Comment: updated answer. try echo $sql, copy the output and paste it into phpmyadmin and see what you get too.

Comment: It just added the record in the database :) and showed me the message 'Successful', still trying to understand why it was not working before. Anyway Thanks a lot :)

Comment: can you answer the other question that I asked yesterday on how to retrieve images from MySQL database. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807220/how-to-view-get-image-back-from-mysql-database